# Wildfly - 10.x - WELD-001414: Bean name is ambiguous. Name csfFLOWDISCOVERYCDIHELPER resolves to beans

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, wildfly-10

- **Server** - WildFly - 10.1.0
- **JSF version** - 2.2
- **Primefaces** - 5.0

I am trying to deploy `.war` file in `WildFly 10.1.0` server. Earlier I was running it on `JBoss 7.1` and we had it working fine. But now when I try to deploy the application in `WildFly` server and am getting below set of exceptions which makes to failed deployment.

```
09:05:02,630 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application.view] (MSC service thread 1-3) Unable to obtain CDI 1.1 utilities for Mojarra
09:05:02,650 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.flow] (MSC service thread 1-3) Unable to obtain CDI 1.1 utilities for Mojarra
09:05:02,897 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."MyApplication.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."MyApplication.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001414: Bean name is ambiguous. Name csfFLOWDISCOVERYCDIHELPER resolves to beans:
  - Managed Bean [class com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIHelper] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any],
  - Managed Bean [class com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIHelper] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$5.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:134)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$5.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:130)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:63)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:56)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

09:05:02,971 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "MyApplication.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"MyApplication.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"MyApplication.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001414: Bean name is ambiguous. Name csfFLOWDISCOVERYCDIHELPER resolves to beans:
  - Managed Bean [class com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIHelper] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any],
  - Managed Bean [class com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIHelper] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"MyApplication.war\".WeldStartService"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
09:05:03,041 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "MyApplication.war" (runtime-name : "MyApplication.war")
09:05:03,068 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."MyApplication.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."MyApplication.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
```

I am not really getting where this exception is pointing to. The error isn't clear too. I have found other SO Post regarding this error but those were with `GlassFish` server. Have anyone come across similar type of issue and got this resolved. I would be really thankful if someone points me in the proper direction or has any resolution for the same.

Comment: Looks like there are two CDI jars in classpath thus giving conflict to the bean. Please check.

Comment: @OTM.. Where exactly I need to look for this?

Comment: Pleese see the class loading precedence section in  https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly

Comment: Great.. posted your comments as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having jsf-api and jsf-impl jar versions in the application which are different from the versions of the app server implementation causes this problem. Removing application provided jars from the WEB-INF/lib folder and using the server provided jars solves the problem.